# Non Responsive Webpage (Mobile)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

hey guys i'm relatively new to css/html/responsiveness design so sorry if this is a basic question. i'm trying to make a certain page take the full width on mobile devices.

the issue being, on the following page, the largest container still only takes 3/4's of viewport in mobile:

http://stkildafitnesstrainer.com.au/our-trainers.html

i've tried: width = device-width, height = device-height, user-scalable = no, which works as a quick fix but obviously is by no means ideal as it alienates those who need zoom so am not going to use this.

the rest of the pages (like: http://stkildafitnesstrainer.com.au/about-us.html) take up the full width. i'm not really sure how else i should tackle this.

Comment: This is because you have 2 columns on the trainer's page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your head your meta viewport missing the initial-scale of 1

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
```

here is the right code